# loading .rdl file to a simple asp.net project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, rdlc, reportbuilder3.0

i want a sample tutorial for loading a .rdl report file that is created using report builder3.0 to a asp.net web page.The tutorials in web available take all way through SSRS and BIDS but i want simple MVC project with report builder 3.0 which are independet of each other.Please provide links for learning the basics for .rdl creation and on how to use then in a MVC project.I intend to use VS2008 and report builder3.0

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2009/11/25/rendering-an-rdlc-directly-to-the-response-stream-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: I have already tried that link already there the "Website Data Sources" doesn't show up my required table ie, 'Customers' says no data source available! all the previous steps i get perfectly fine

Comment: Try this one : http://myprogramminglife.com/rdlc-report-in-asp-net-mvc-3/

Comment: and can you post what u tried..

Comment: i am trying the second link you provided where the same problem at  step No:8 adding report data source doesn't show up Adventureworks DB! (whatever i tried is same as that in the screen shots in the link)Am using VS2008 (how to attach screenshot here?)

Comment: Instead of adventures db try your own local db..

Comment: Can you suggest me something like - Loading a .rdl to web page as in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337091(v=sql.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2 ...it looks complicated and i don't have mentioned report to load.Is there a full example available? i did some search but couldn't find one.

Comment: can you please update your post with the code what u tried till now.?